# How to handle hidden select dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, select, dropdown

```
Faced the situation when using Select class, selenium complains that "element not interactable".
```

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nePVX.png)

```
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.select")).click();
        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("phonePrefix")));
        select.selectByIndex(5);
```

[Output from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8G2N.png)

anyway I found a way to select element from dropdown by looping through the List and selecting by text.....

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.select")).click();
        
        WebElement drop = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select"));
        
        List<WebElement> countryies = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul[class='select-options'] li"));
        for(WebElement i:countryies) {
            System.out.println(i.getText());
            if(i.getText().contains("+93 Afghanistan")) {
                i.click();
                break;
            }
        }
```

But the question is why i cannot use Select class and select.getFirstSelectedOption() and how to handle this?
Thnx

P.s Also tried some explicit wait.

```
    driver.get("https://banking.idram.am/Account/login");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.select")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("phonePrefix")));
        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("phonePrefix")));
        select.selectByIndex(5);
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvnMZ.png)

Comment: How long is your implicit wait? Are you sure that the dropdown is ready to be clicked when you call `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.select")).click();`? You are probably calling that function prematurely. The page might be still loading which explains why the element is not interactable. You will probably be better off using `WebDriverWait` to obtain the dropdown when the `ExpectedConditions` is met (i.e. `elementToBeClickable`).

Comment: Yes, I have used also explicit wait with condition "elementToBeClickable "for 10 sec, but it is not becoming clickable)

Comment: Actually this step `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.select")).click()` is successful, and it is openning the dropdown box, but the rest is not

Comment: Can you copy and paste the part of the DOM that contains this dropdown?

Comment: `                          <div class="login-input-outer">
                                <div class="input-control">
                                    <select class="phonePrefix" required="required" name="phonePrefix" id="phonePrefix"></select>
                                    <label for="phonePrefix" data-tr-code="countryCode" class="active"></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-control tel">
`

Comment: Give me a minute to update my answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image you posted with the HTML code, you should select the item from the dropdown in this manner:

```
public class DropDownDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "YOUR_PATH_TO_DRIVER_EXE_HERE");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://banking.idram.am/Account/login");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement divSelect = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofMillis(100)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.select")));
        divSelect.click();
        WebElement option = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10), Duration.ofMillis(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[text()='+93 Afghanistan']")));
        option.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000); // only to see the result
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

If using Selenium 3, remove the `Duration.ofXXX()` and just pass the numeric values directly to the constructor.

> ***why I cannot use Select class** and select.getFirstSelectedOption() and how to handle this?*

```
<select class="phonePrefix select-hidden" required="required" name="phonePrefix" id="phonePrefix">
    ...
</select>
```

As you can see from the posted snippet, `Select` element is using `select-hidden` class to implement the dropdown. Therefore, Selenium cannot interact with it. What this application is using is called a *[Bootstrap Dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp)*. Also, the easiest way to figure out which one to use (i.e. select vs. ul/li) is by inspecting the page and select one of the options. When you do this, it goes to the `li` element rather than to the `option` element.

Comment: Unfortunately with xpath result is the same)
Here is the link of the page https://banking.idram.am/Account/login

Comment: I am in the process of editing. Give me a few  minutes.

Comment: If this does not work, you will need to Copy and paste the error stack trace in your post, not as a comment. I need more detail. Anyway, it is late here in Texas. I am going to bed. Got to get up early tomorrow.

Comment: I just saw the comment with the link. I think I know what's going on.

Comment: I tried the posted answer and works for me. If it works for you, don't forget to select my answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: The solution works for selecting, I also posted solution for selecting(using loop) but you did not use Select() class, the question is why it is not possible to use 
` 
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("phonePrefix")));
        select.selectByIndex(5);
`